# Java garbage collection of private field

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Consider the following class

```
public class A {
    private final Map<Integer, HeavyObject> cache;
    public HeavyObject getThing(); 
}
```

Assuming references to *cache* cannot be leaked out, will *cache* be garbage collected when instances of A are? I'm also assuming HeavyObject eventually goes out of scope.

I have reasons to believe that's not the case by looking into the heap there are cases where instances of A are deallocated while HeavyObject eventually causes the JVM to halt for to much GC.

Addressing one of the comments. getThing() is called within a function looking like this:

```
void compute(A a) {
  ...
  while(condition) {
    ...
    HeavyThing thing = a.getThing();
    ...
  }
}
```

So there's no way HeavyThing gets out of the while.

The lifecycle of *a* is

```
Set<A> theAs = new HashSet();
while(true) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) theAs.add(new A());
  theAs = computeNewAs(theAs);
}
```

Note that the tricky bit is that computeNewAs always keeps 8 instances of A from the older set.
So when looking at the memory allocation at some point I see always 8 instances of A but a huge quantity of HashMaps and HeavyObject

Comment: Which GC (G1 or CMS) do you use? Also, it should to note that deallocation order can be arbitrary.

Comment: If an instance is no longer reachable it will eventually be collected. But there are many ways to leak instances, that are not really obvious. You might want to provide a minimal example that actually produces a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you are confused.

It seems like your problem isn't whether the `cache` Map gets gc'ed, it's whether the `HeavyObject`s get gc'ed. And your HeavyObjects can definitely leak out

```
public HeavyObject getThing();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with a code like this:

```
Map<Integer, HeavyObject> cache = new HashMap<Integer, HeavyObject>(){
    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println("I'm gone");
    }
};
System.gc();
```

Answer (score 1):

The access modifier of fields is completely irrelevant. It doesn’t matter whether references *can* “leak out”, when the object owning the field is unreachable. At that point, nothing can leak out anymore and all that matters is whether it *has* “leaked out”, or in more correct terms, whether the object is still reachable.

Having a `private` field may help structuring the code in a way that the reference isn’t used anywhere else, but of course, that doesn’t guaranty anything. There might be still a method within the class handling out the reference. But as said, what matters is whether it actually happens.

Regarding your observation, it’s hard to say *what* you are actually observing, but in the code you have posted, there is no `HashMap` nor `HeavyObject` instance ever created, so its not sufficient to tell whether the observation is reasonable. But if an `A` instance holds a reference to a `HashMap` potentially containing multiple `HeavyObject` instances, it’s entirely plausible, that there are significantly more `HeavyObject` instances than `A` instances. If that’s contradicting your expectation, you should rethink you design.

If you suspect a memory leak, you should use a profiling tool, e.g. JVisualVM, which is shipped with the JDK, and let it create a heap dump, and search for the pending instances and inspect the actual references to these objects.